# RESTful API design: token auth

Tags: node.js, laravel, rest, api, microservices

I'm designing a standard compliant RESTful API. Each resource has its own end points. There are no verbs in my resources etc...

We use JWT for stateless client authentication.

How can I still utilise a semantic design with auth routes?

E.g.

```
/auth/login
/auth/logout
/auth/reset
/auth/forgot
```

These endpoint contain verbs... I can't workout how to best name the auth resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using auth, you can use the verb `users`. Hence the routes would change to

```
POST /users # Signup
POST /users/token # Login
PUT /users # Update profile
GET /users/me # Profile of logged in user
POST /users/reset
POST /users/forgot
DELETE /users/:id # deactivate account
```

Now this is more of a personal preference but the endpoints are more or less compatible with [best practices](http://nodewebapps.com/2017/02/13/six-best-practices-when-building-rest-apis/).